# Find on has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have 3 models: Users, Customers, Issues. Below is the code for these models

Customer model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :se
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :issues
end
```

Issues model:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

Users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ses
  has_many :customers
  has_many :issues, :through => :customers

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name,     :last_name, :cell_ph, :area


end
```

I would like to display only the issues that belong to a particular user. I am having problems making this work. Can someone suggest how I might create an index method that would accomplish this?

Here is my index method where I'm trying to use devise's current_user method to identify the user who's logged in to the view:

```
  def index
    @issues = Issue.where(:user == :current_user)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @issues }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're doing because an Issue doesn't have a user.

According to Rails guides (second example on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association session), you can nest the `has_many` using a `has_many :through`.

So you should be able to do this:

`current_user.issues`

Comment: Thanks! This was good direction that helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rodrigo's answer, you have some bad syntax on this line:

```
@issues = Issue.where(:user == :current_user)
```

That's never going to return any results because `:user == :current_user` is performing a comparison of two distinct Ruby `Symbol` objects. That always returns false, so your statement essentially equates to `Issue.where(false)`.

This is closer to what you need:

```
@issues = Issue.where(:user => current_user)
```

This still doesn't fix the problem you have (`Issue` does not have many `User`s), but at least the meaning is correct.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. This was helpful to my learning.